# Avoid infinite loop when updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have to update a state of items and see the changes right away. When I'm doing this below, I get an infinite loop.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const playersInFight = gameData.characters.filter((x) =>
      fightData.currentPositionInfoDTOS.some((y) => y.entityId == x.id)
    );

    let orderedCharacters = addPlayers(
      playersInFight,
      fightData.currentPositionInfoDTOS,
      fightData.turnOrder
    );
    setAllCharacterCards(orderedCharacters);

  }, [fightData, gameData, fightInfo, allCharacterCards, allCharacters]);
```

I have tried also like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const playersInFight = gameData.characters.filter((x) =>
      fightData.currentPositionInfoDTOS.some((y) => y.entityId == x.id)
    );

    let orderedCharacters = addPlayers(
      playersInFight,
      fightData.currentPositionInfoDTOS,
      fightData.turnOrder
    );
    setAllCharacterCards(orderedCharacters);

  }, [fightData, gameData, fightInfo, allCharacterCards, allCharacters]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAllCharacterCards(allCharacterCards);
  }, [allCharacterCards]);
```

And thanks to that I don't have an infinite loop, but to see the changes I have to refresh the page...
How can I solve this?

Update:
Here is my return:

```
return (
    <section>
        <div className="player-fight">
          {allCharacterCards ? (
            <div>
              {allCharacterCards.map((c, idx) => {
                return (
                  <li key={idx} className="player-fight-bottom__player-card">
                    <CardComponentPlayerCard
                      id={c.id}
                      name={c.name}
                      money={c.money}
                      health={c.health}
                      maxHealth={c.maxHealth}
                      mine={false}
                      description={c.description}
                      statuses={c.statuses}
                      image={c.photoPath}
                    />
                  </li>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <LoadingSpinner />
          )}
        </div>
    </section>
  );
```

Comment: Do all those dependencies trigger a change [fightData, gameData, fightInfo, allCharacterCards, allCharacters], I mean what is the condition to update allCharacters,
Looks like you could need a useMemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid infinite looping you need to remove `allCharacterCards` from `useEffect` dependency array.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    const playersInFight = gameData.characters.filter((x) =>
      fightData.currentPositionInfoDTOS.some((y) => y.entityId == x.id)
    );

    let orderedCharacters = addPlayers(
      playersInFight,
      fightData.currentPositionInfoDTOS,
      fightData.turnOrder
    );

    setAllCharacterCards([...orderedCharacters]);

  }, [fightData, gameData, fightInfo, allCharacters]);
```

**Explanation** (after question edited)

```
    setAllCharacterCards([...orderedCharacters]);
```

This should fix your problem.

Since `allCharacterCards` is an array of `objects` you need to use spread operator `...` to let react know that you are updating state everytime with new values.
Read more about - `Deep copy vs shallow copy`.

Comment: @coddin.dev I don't have an infinite loop, but the displayed data didn't change

Comment: Could you provide your jsx also? To know how you are displaying it.

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).